# Not able to get row-id in ag-grid custom tooltip

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have created table using ag grid with custom tool tip and Filter by rows. Assuming that default grid has 4 rows and row index would be like the below

```
row-index: 0
row-index: 1
row-index: 2
row-index: 3
```

While filtering the rows, row index is resetting every time 0,1,2...  All I want is row id which is constant.

How to get **row-id** in ag grid custom tooltip

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ITooltipAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';   

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-component',
  templateUrl: './ag-grid-tooltip.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ag-grid-tooltip.component.scss'],
})
export class AgGridTooltipComponent implements ITooltipAngularComp {

  private params: any;

  public data: string;
  public show: boolean;

  constructor() {

  }

  agInit(params): void {
    this.params = params;
    console.log(this.params.rowIndex); // working fine always starts with 0


   console.log(this.params.rowId); // undefined
console.log(this.params.node.id); // can not read id.



      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement getRowNodeId function like this.

```
gridOptions.getRowNodeId = (item) => {
   return item.id;
};
```